# A Poincare inequality on fractional Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth domain. Does the following inequality hold for all $u \in H^s_0(\Omega)$:

$$\lVert u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C|u|_{H^s_0(\Omega)}$$
where the right hand side is the $H^s_0(\Omega)$ seminorm.

$H^s_0$ is defined as an interpolaton space of $H^1_0$ and $L^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will also depend on the dimension of $\Omega$. Roughly speaking, the embedding theorem works the same for fraction ordered Sobolev space. Please check Theorem 6.14 from this [book](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5860.html), and some related theorems from there as well.